# Html2Canvas: how to get the center part of a dom element

Tags: javascript, frontend, html2canvas

[Screenshot of the area](https://i.stack.imgur.com/atMDV.png)
I only want the snapshot getting from the html2canvas to be the center part (approximately the area between orange lines) of this blue area. What parameters should I set for the method?

My current implementation:

```
    let doc = document.getElementById("texera-workflow-editor") || document.body;
    html2canvas(doc, {
      allowTaint: true,
      useCORS: true,
      backgroundColor: "rgba(0,0,0,0)",
    }).then(canvas => {
     ...)}
```

Comment: What in the HTML structure defines the area you want - or how else is it defined? For example do you want to get rid of all (or some of...in which case, what proportion) the top and bottom of the canvas that just consist of rows of white (or are they transparent)? pixels?

Comment: @A Haworth I just wanted to get the center/middle part of the area. The width of the resulting snapshot should be the same, but what should I set for to get the correct height of the cutting snapshot?

Comment: Well, it depends on what you want. Could you tell me what the bits you don't want look like. Are they white or are they transparent. You can get rid of these, or some of them depending on what you want, but given all the different device aspect ratios your users might be on we can't know in advance where the 'middle bit' actually is, we have to go down looking at each row. So, do you want to get rid of everything down to the first bit of canvas that has something in it, or do you want to keep some sort of padding/margin?

Comment: @AHaworth Let's say I want to cut off 100px for both the bottom and top of the area, so if the height is 800px, I want the height of the resulting image to be 600px (800 - 100 -100).

Comment: Will this be OK for any aspect ratio device? It's not possible to tell from the code you have given because we don't know how that white space is created.

Comment: @AHaworth Yes, let's assume it is fixed.